# C# building on Sublime Text Build 4143 on macOS

Tags: c#, macos, sublimetext

I have an issue with Sublime Text and C# compiler, look, I'm studying C# fundaments and I work building the code on Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code, when I run the code this work fine but sometimes I want to work an only single .cs archive on sublime text because I don't need to save the archive and I like this program to write code, the problem is this, when I try to run the code, this starts and works fine but when the console asks me to type a key the code doesn't continue, I have this .JSON code to run C#.

**1. ** from [Sublime Build System not finding code in working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701280/sublime-build-system-not-finding-code-in-working-directory)

```
{
    "working_dir": "${folder:${project_path:${file_path}}}",
    "selector": "source.cs",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Build",
            "shell_cmd": "dotnet build",
            "word_wrap": false,
            "quiet": true,
        },
        {
            "name": "Clean",
            "shell_cmd": "dotnet clean"
        },
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "dotnet run"
        },
        {
            "name": "Run Interactive",
            "cmd": ["dotnet", "run"],
            "target": "terminus_open",
            "auto_close": false,
        }
    ],
}
```

I can continue with my application but when it asks me to press a key to continue this don't function, maybe the problem is very simple but I repeat that I am learning, thanks!

- I want to compile C# in Sublime Text
- I want to build a .JSON that help me to run all the C# codes that I make

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't send input to running program in Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254765/cant-send-input-to-running-program-in-sublime-text)